# Blazor - Open page without NavMenu

Tags: .net, blazor-server-side

I'm using the standard Blazor server side template with a Navigation menu on a left pane and the different razor page on the right.
I would like to call a url on that web application where the NavMenu will not be displayed (but still on the other pages).
How can I achieve to avoid this NavMenu ? By a particular route (avoiding the MainLayout.razor) ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've found an example creating another _Host, see: https://github.com/asabbah1/ASBlog/tree/8e6cf20c8d8327d162165a175f0d79d64174fb4f/ASBlog.Web